# Angular 4 spa template deployment on iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio-2017, iis-8

I created a angular 4 application using VS 2017 angular spa template and it works fine in my local machine. I'm having issues setting up the project on the server IIS.
I have published the files on the server, I created a site on the IIS and mapped it to the index.cshtml under the \views\home\ directory. When I browse the site I'm getting http Error 404.3 - Not found.

Target framework is net461 and iis version is 8.5

Could you please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: it may be the connection string issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install aspnetcoremodule for IIS to resolve this issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?tabs=aspnetcore2x